# Why does FIDO2's spec not mention FIDO UAF as a related standard?

Tags: fido, webauthn

Why does FIDO2's spec not mention FIDO UAF as a related standard? I wonder if FIDO UAF is still relevant. Will FIDO UAF be deprecated eventually in favor of FIDO2? Why do they co-exist if they fulfil the same purpose?

What I already know:

FIDO2 consists of two standards that together enable a web app to communicate with an authenticator.

- CTAP2 (CTAP2 superseded CTAP which was earlier called FIDO U2F)
- WebAuthn

Then there is also FIDO UAF (not to confuse with U2F), which seems to serve the same purpose as FIDO2. Looking at [FIDO2's specs](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.1-ps-20210615/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.1-ps-errata-20220621.html) the term "UAF" is not even mentioned once.

[In this stackoverflow thread (2017)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151904/why-is-fido-u2f-an-entirely-different-standard-from-fido-uaf-instead-of-just-a-s) @FredericMARTIN mentions that the two standards were put forward by different players. @Qingbao mentions that FIDO UAF serves to support single-factor authentication. However also with FIDO2 single-factor/passwordless authentication is absolutely possible (see [yubico.com](https://www.yubico.com/authentication-standards/fido2/)). [In this other thread (2017)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124697/from-a-credential-flow-perspective-whats-the-difference-between-fido-uaf-and-fi) @FredericMARTIN writes that WebAuthn would be the "non-messy" FIDO UAF.

The specs of both FIDO UAF and FIDO2 can be found on the [FIDO Alliance's website](https://fidoalliance.org/specifications/download).

Comment: Why must one standard reference another?

Comment: Have you seen this? This page explains the architectural differences: https://fidoalliance.org/specifications/

Comment: I googled "FIDO UAF vs FIDO2" and found numerous articles explaining the difference, including the linked duplicate.

Comment: thank you! the link commented in the question you marked as "related" answered my question.
Even tough the question marked as related does not specifically ask for FIDO UAF, a comment under th question by @natevw answered my question by providing a link explaining the history and relation of the protocols.